# перемещение по таблице данных в верх и вниз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть многомерный массив:

```
var arr = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
          ];
```

как по нему перемещаться?

есть текст: Да, у меня 5.

При нахождении в тексте цифры 5, я должен ее заменить на 2.
При нахождении в тексте цифры 7, я должен ее заменить на 4.
И так далее. (пример хотя бы на движение в вверх, дальше разберусь)

Можно все опустить кроме функции которая принимает значение переменной и на ее основе выбирает нужное значение.

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
          ];
let str='Да, у меня 9',
num=parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0]) //выцепляем число из строки
arr.some((v,i)=>{
  let j=v.findIndex(v=>v===num), //ищем нужное число в одном из массивов
  isgood=j!=-1 //условие на то, что наши поиски успешны
  if(isgood){ //если число найдено
    let newval=arr[i-1][j] //берём массив, стоящий уровнем выше
    if(newval) console.log(str.replace(num,newval)) //если мы не вышли за пределы двухмерного массива, то всё впорядке, заменяем число в строке и выводим её
  }
  return isgood
})
```

Интерактивный примерчик:

```js
var arr = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
          ];
$('button').click(()=>{
  let num=parseInt($('input').val()) //число из инпута
  arr.some((v,i)=>{
    let j=v.findIndex(v=>v===num), //ищем нужное число в одном из массивов
    isgood=j!=-1 //условие на то, что наши поиски успешны
    if(isgood){ //если число найдено
      let newval=arr[i-1][j] //берём массив, стоящий уровнем выше
      if(newval) console.log($('span').text()+newval) //если мы не вышли за пределы двухмерного массива, то всё впорядке, заменяем число в строке и выводим её
    }
    return isgood
  })
})
```

```css
input{
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Да, у меня </span><input value=5><p>
<button>Преобразовать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, можно все представить так

3n+1;
3n+2;
3n+3;

Допустим число 5.
Позицию мы не знаем,поэтому выйдет 3n+x=5; 3n=5-x;
x меняется от 1 до 3 и число целое.

```js
function findPos(number, arr){
 let pos = null;
 let row = null;
 for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  if((number - i) % 3 === 0) {
   const temp = (number - i) / 3;
   pos = i - 1;
   row = temp === 0 ? temp : temp - 1;
   break;
  }
 }
 console.log(arr[row][pos]);
}

var arr = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
          ];
    
findPos(5, arr);
findPos(7, arr);
findPos(3, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Без переборов. Но думаю можно было бы кое-что еще короче написать, не додумался.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

function get (arr, find) {
  let columns = arr.length
  let joined = [].concat(...arr)
  let index = joined.indexOf(find) + 1
  let column = Math.ceil(index / joined.length * columns) - 1
  let indexUp = arr[column].indexOf(find)
  let upColumn = arr[column - 1]
  
  return (upColumn && upColumn[indexUp]) || null
}

console.log(get(arr, 8)) // 5
console.log(get(arr, 6)) // 3
console.log(get(arr, 3)) // null
```